# Track Controller Method Run Times

Tags: codeigniter, logging

I'd like to write a line in the log with the duration every controller method takes to run (public and private). Originally I set this up as one would imagine, very manually, subtract start seconds from end seconds and write log, with that code at the start and end of every method.

Keeping as DRY as possible, I'm wondering if someone knows a way to abstract this so I don't have to write the same code in every single method.

This is using Codeigniter.

Comment: Have you looked at the available profiler? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html

Comment: Yea, but what I'm looking for would be to use that in a "pre/post controller method hook" so I don't have to set the start and end in every single method.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't even need the profiler class; can just use benchmark class:

*application/config/config.php*:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

*application/config/hooks.php*:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'MyProfiler',
                                'function' => 'start_profiler',
                                'filename' => 'profiler.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                );

// or 'post_system' to benchmark page render too
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'MyProfiler',
                                'function' => 'stop_profiler',
                                'filename' => 'profiler.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                );
```

*application/hooks/profiler.php*:

```
class MyProfiler {

    var $CI;

    function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function start_profiler() {
        $this->CI->benchmark->mark('code_start');
    }

    function stop_profiler() {
        $this->CI->benchmark->mark('code_end');
        echo $this->CI->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');//or log
    }
}
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html

Comment: This is definitely the right direction, but I don't think it'll quite do what I'm looking for (and I'm thinking I'll have to do it outside of the benchmark class). I'm looking for hooks that run pre and post a *method* run. For example, if I have a method that has a loop that runs 10 calls to private methods in the same controller, I want the run time for the public method, and each private method that runs.